# Fourier Transform of a kernel

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, partial-derivative, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

Let $\omega \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ and define $u(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\frac{(x-y)^{\perp}}{|x - y|^{2}}\omega(y)dy$, where

$(x-y)^{\perp} = \begin{bmatrix}x_{2} - y_{2}\\-x_{1} + y_{1} \end{bmatrix}$.

Show that $\partial_{x_{1}}u_{1}$ is related to $\omega$ by a singular integral operator.

Idea: I have tried to compute the Fourier transform of $\frac{y^{\perp}}{|y|^{2}}$, but did not see anything dropping out.

Comment: Is u suppose to be $\mathbb{R}^{2}$-valued?

Comment: It is a vector and so I would think it is the case.